# UndefinedError: 'login_user_form' is undefined

Tags: html, flask

Currently I'm building a website for practice purposes. I am using Flask-security to implement the log in and register system. I m getting this error as stated in the title. Here is my codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Main</title>
    <meta name=":viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale =1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!--NavBar Design-->
    <link href="{{url_for('static',filename='navbar_design.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<!--HEADER-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-static-top">
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">

        <img style="max-width:80px; " src="{{url_for('static',filename='v4.png')}}" >

    </div>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a style="font-size:25px; margin-top:19px;" href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="font-size:25px; margin-top:19px; " >Main Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Survey Application Form</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Check The Result of The Survey Application</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a style="font-size:21px; margin-top:14px;" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a style="font-size:21px; margin-top:14px;" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Log In</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</nav>

<!--body-->
{% from "security/_macros.html" import render_field_with_errors, render_field %}
{% include "security/_messages.html" %}

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!--Modal Head-->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Log In</h2>
        </div>

<!--Modal Body-->
      <div claas = "modal-body">
        <form action="{{ url_for_security('login') }}" method="POST" name="login_user_form">
              {{ login_user_form.hidden_tag() }}
              {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.email, class="form-control") }}
              {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.password, class="form-control") }}
              {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.remember ) }}
              {{ render_field(login_user_form.next) }}
              <div class="modal-footer">
                {{ render_field(login_user_form.submit, class="btn btn-success") }}
              </div>

        </form>
        Dont have an account ?{% include "security/_menu.html" %}

      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>




<!--Footer-->
<div class = "navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
 <div class = "container-fluid">
</div>

</div>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Inside my flask, i have something like this

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('main.html')
```

this error will give me error. But if i changed the template, and then access the login by changing the URL, eg,https://127.0.0.1:5000/login. This approach will generate NO error, but this not i want, i want the above able to run . any help will be appreciated ! thanks!

EDIT:
[image: screenshots of the error]

Comment: what is your question ` login_user_form undefined ?` or html not render in browser ?

Comment: You aren't passing any context to `render_template`

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the error traceback.

Looks like your index function isn''t passing proper parameters to the template.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    login_user_form = LoginForm()
    return render_template('main.html',login_user_form)
```

**EDIT**

The LoginForm class should look like this.

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    username = StringField("Enter your username",validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField("Enter your password",validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

For more detail , check this link-
[Flask-wtf quickstart](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: HI, thanks for the feedback. Can you explain what should I include in the 'YOUR FORM CLASS' as I m really new to python Flask.Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer, what class I defined is just an example .Check the docs link for more detail.